# Microsoft Interop: Word compare .doc with .docx c#

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop, document

I've developed an app that gets two documents and then opens Word to compare changes between them. It works perfectly with 2 .docx or 2 .doc but if I try to compare .doc with .docx it opens *only* the .doc in compatibility mode and doesn't do a comparison. Here is the code I use to compare:

```
  object fileToOpen = (object)rutaVersion1;
  string fileToCompare = rutaVersion2;

  object missing = Type.Missing;

  doc1 = wordApp.Documents.Open(fileToOpen, Visible: true);
  doc1.TrackRevisions = true;
  doc1.ShowRevisions = true;
  doc1.PrintRevisions = true;

  wordApp.ActiveDocument.Compare(fileToCompare, missing, WdCompareTarget.wdCompareTargetCurrent, true, true, false, false, false);
  wordApp.Activate();
  wordApp.WindowState = WdWindowState.wdWindowStateMinimize;
  wordApp.WindowState = WdWindowState.wdWindowStateMaximize;
```

rutaVersion1 points to .doc file, and rutaVersion2 to .docx. Using Office365 but having the same issue with other Office version. If I manually compare them it works.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Maybe save the .doc file as a temporary .docx?

Comment: Document comparison isn't really my forté, but... 1) I'd expect a *.doc to open in compatibility mode in Word 2007 and later. 2) Does it make any difference if you switch rutaVErsion1 and rutaVersion2, so that Word does the comparison "the other way round"? 3) What's the problem with the comparison you're getting in your code / how does it differ from doing it manually?

Comment: @CindyMeister 1) It's OK that it's open that mode, thought it would cause some kind of warning and fail to open but no. 2) No, it happens the same, also I can't switch that vars because comparison would be wrong, it would show older changes as newer. 3) This code doesn't give an output but opens Word. It should open Word in comparison mode but it opens normal mode showing .doc file. It shouldn't differ, is just a module of a bigger app that should open 2 downloaded documents and compare them.

Comment: @MickyD I've tryed but that code is running on a child thread and it seems to not allow me to write a new file. Still trying.

Comment: When I test in VBA I do get a mark-up in the *.doc file. I did change your code in one (perhaps important) respect: Instead of `wordApp.ActiveDocument.Compare` I use `doc1.Compare`. I also don't change any Window states, but that shouldn't make any difference... If that doesn't help, which version of Word are you running?